# How do we get a parametric equation of the intersection of 2 3d solids.

Tags: calculus, functions

A question on my textbook asked to find the parametric equation for the intersection between $x^2+y^2=4$ and $z=xy$. My question isn't much on why the solution $x=2*\sin(t),\ y=2\cos(t)$ and $z=4\sin(t)\cos(t)$ works, but more on how we get that solution.

Are we supposed to replace x and y with trig functions whenever we see $x^2+y^2$? Theoretically, if we replace $x^2$ with $t$ and $y^2$ with $4-t$ the equation would still be satisfied, so why do we default to $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions?

Answer (score 1):

$(2\sin t,2\cos t)$ is a “natural” parameterization of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ in the $x$-$y$ plane that generates the cylinder, and one that is easily applied to $z=xy$. There are certainly others, and the most convenient one depends entirely on what it is you’re going to do with the parameterization.

However, your proposed $x^2=t$ and $y^2=4-t$ quickly goes nowhere. How would you represent a point with a negative $x$-coordinate using this substitution?

Comment: My thinking is that when you do the square root of both sides, you have to find the positive and negative solutions for x and y. I graphed this in a program and it seems that if you include both positive and negative solutions, it is equivalent to the parametrization with sin and cos

Comment: @TimothyLiu In other words, you can only parameterize part of the curve that way.

Answer (score 0):

> Are we supposed to replace $x$ and $y$ with trig functions whenever we see $x^2+y^2$?

Here you are looking to describe the points of the intersection of two 3D surfaces, a cylinder mantle and a hyperbolic paraboloid, so you can expect some curve, parameterized by one parameter.

The possible parametrization is not unique, order and velocity might differ.

Your trig functions just form a very common parametrization of a circle, going counter clock wise, so it might be a service to the reader to simplify calculations.